# Angular-Js unable to push data into array of controller

Tags: angularjs

HTML:-

```
<div ng-controller="countryController">
        {{name}}
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="country in countries">
                {{ country.name }}
                <ul ng-show="country.states.length > 0">
                    <li ng-repeat="state in country.states">
                        {{ state.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="text" ng-model="newState">
                <a href ng-click="addStateState(country)">Add </a>
                {{newState}}
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

When I key in newState model it appears in client side.
Now i try to get that value into controller and try to push in array of states, its unable to add into states array.

JS Controller:-

```
myApp.factory('countryService', function($http){
var baseUrl = 'services/'
return {
    getCountries : function(){
        return $http.get(baseUrl + 'getcountries.php');
    }
};
```

});

```
myApp.controller('countryController', function($scope, countryService){
countryService.getCountries().success(function(data){
    $scope.countries = data;
});

$scope.addStateState = function(country){
    country.states.push({'name' : $scope.newState});
    $scope.newState = "";
};
```

});

Comment: Can you please explain the error you are getting? It looks ok.

Comment: A Codepen or a plunkr would be very helpful.

Comment: @Mike is right.  In the future make a plunkr and post it to make the answer easier for others to give.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that your $scope.newState is not available inside $scope.newStateState function.  It is bad practice to manipulate an object like $scope within a $scope function.  In fact, you are creating multiple multiple objects that are not the same as the $scope that you inject; otherwise, the input boxes for two different countries should match.

Working Plunkr below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HG3zWG?p=preview

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('countryController', function($scope){
  $scope.countries = [
      { name: 'USA', states:[
          {name: 'Virginia'},
          {name: 'Utah'}
        ]
      },
      { name: 'Brazil', states:[
          {name: 'Pernabuco'}
        ]
      }
    ];

  $scope.addStateState = function(country, data){
    country.states.push({'name' : data.newState});
    data.newState = "";
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="countryController">
        {{name}}
               <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="country in countries">
                {{ country.name }}
                          <ul ng-show="country.states.length > 0">
            <li ng-repeat="state in country.states">
                        {{ state.name }}
                    </li>
          </ul>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.newState" />
          <a href="" ng-click="addStateState(country, data)">Add </a>

                {{data.newState}}
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with things like ng-repeat, ng-if, or ng-include, they each create a new scope. This means that when you try to bind to a primitive on the root level of that scope, it will get dereferences when you update the value. So, you need to put your primitives inside of an object. John Papa's style guide recommends making a "vm" property on your scope. vm stands for view model.

Here is a jsfiddle of how to use it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fbLycnpg/

```
vm.newState
```

Comment: Great description.  You going to host at ng-conf?  You were hilarious last year #endofconversationinstackoverflowcomment

Comment: Wow! Thanks @chris. That made my day, and the day just started.